# How to navigate between windows in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, click

I have tried to set up a click event for a button that opens another window,but the error I'm getting at `NavigationService` is that the project doesn't contain a definition for it.

This is how I'm trying to call the page at present:

```
private void conditioningBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("TrainingFrm.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction with this or show alternatives to this method for window navigation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

NavigationService is for browser navigation within WPF. What you are trying to do is change to a different window `TrainingFrm`.

To go to a different window, you should do this:

```
private void conditioningBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newForm = new TrainingFrm(); //create your new form.
    newForm.Show(); //show the new form.
    this.Close(); //only if you want to close the current form.
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want your WPF application to behave like a browser, then you would need to create `Page`s instead of Forms, and then use a `Frame` in your application to do the navigation. See [this example](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation).

Comment: That worked anyways thanks :) I just got a book on WPF so hopefully Ill gain a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to navigate from Window to Window:

```
private void conditioningBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 window1 = new Window1();
    // window1.Show(); // Win10 tablet in tablet mode, use this, when sub Window is closed, the main window will be covered by the Start menu.
    window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

If you want to navigate from Window to Page:

```
private void conditioningBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   NavigationWindow window = new NavigationWindow();
   window.Source = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
   window.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to use NavigationService you should use the Page and not the Window class